# How to calculate the derivatives of absolute value?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I need to calculate derivatives of absolute value as follows
$$
\frac{d}{dr_1}\lvert r_1-r_2\rvert
$$
somewhere in my calculations. When I simply use `D[Abs[r1-r2],r1]`it returns `Abs'[r1-r2]`! and I don't know how to deal with it. Doesn't Mathematica yield an explicit answer in this case?!

Comment: See the above, Try `D[RealAbs[r1 - r2], r1]`  so instead of `D[Abs[x],x]` use `D[RealAbs[x], x]`

Comment: @Nasser Oh, Thanks bro! seems you hit the spot!

Comment: Note that `Abs'[r1 - r2]` is `Derivative[1][Abs][r1 - r2]`; you can in fact give definitions like `Derivative[1][Abs]=Sign` if you like, as `Derivative` is not protected.